# Tailwind grid_template_columns

Tags: tailwind-css

How can we set individual column width in Tailwind?

For example in vanilla CSS I would

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
</div>
```

But, in Tailwind if you apply width to the columns, it breaks the grid.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

it's fairly simple. In grid CSS you can tell each element of the grid in which column or row it should start (See [grid-column-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start)) or end (see [grid-column-end](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end)) and even how many columns it should span.

With tailwind this is very simple (See [Grid column](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column))
col-start-x
col-end-x
col-span-x

With this said, in your case it would be (assuming a 5 column grid)

```html
<div class="grid-container grid grid-cols-5">
  <div class="item1 col-span-1">1</div>
  <div class="item2 col-span-4">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 47):

There is a way to set arbitrary values for columns, I know this question is old but I thought I would share. I'm new to tailwinds myself but I thought maybe someone else might find this helpful:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[20%_80%]">
```

This method also works for setting fixed widths:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-[200px_auto]">
```

In this example the first column will have a fixed width of 200px and the other column would size in auto.

Comment: @Charlotte Wells this should be the accepted answer as the accepted one is a mental model workaround.

Answer (score 8):

To set column width, you either use [Grid Column Start / End](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column) or simple straight forward [Width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width)

[working demo on tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Vpa0WRfrsX)

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-10">
  <div class="col-span-2 bg-purple-200">1</div>
  <div class="col-span-8 bg-purple-300">2</div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="bg-indigo-200 w-1/5">1</div>
  <div class="bg-indigo-300 w-4/5">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set Arbitrary values using brackets: `grid-cols-[20%,80%]`, the same as any other combinations: `grid-cols-[1fr,1.4fr]`.

Thanks [sbaildon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6542409/sbaildon) for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what tailwindcss does is a repeat(n, 1fr), so thats why our friends in other comments tell you to make a 10 grid and then make colspans.

I found my self in that situation many times to and, when I need only 2 columns with, in your case 80% 20%, I do it in the `<style jsx>`. In terms of responsiveness is going to be much, much easier.

Maybe in the future with tailwind JIT we could make this:
[Tailwind grid-template-columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEIe0.png)

But for now we can't, maybe we could ask them, would you join?

Comment: Custom grids using the JIT compiler is a use case explicitly called out in the docs:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support

```html
<!-- Complex grids -->
<div class="grid-cols-[1fr,700px,2fr]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working for mine

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4">
    <div class="col-start-2 col-span-4">01</div>
    <div class="col-start-1 col-end-3">02</div>
</div>
```